TlsException: Handshake failed after sending a bunch of web requests
After i send about 1500-1700 web requests (it's always in that range), i get this error:
TlsException: Handshake failed - error code: UNITYTLS_INTERNAL_ERROR, verify result: UNITYTLS_X509VERIFY_NOT_DONE
Restarting Unity "refreshes" the quota and i can send about the same amount of requests again.
I’m building a webscraper and i need to send about 14000 requests.
There's a delay between each request, and I send a maximum of 5 concurrently to avoid overloading the server.
I also tried the following website for testing, but got the same error:
https://httpbin.org/
Here’s my HttpClient:
private static readonly Lazy<HttpClient> httpClient = new(() => new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler
{
    ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (_, _, _, _) => true,
    ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Automatic,
    SslProtocols = SslProtocols.None
})
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri("https://yugioh.fandom.com/"),
    Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(HTTPCLIENT_TIMEOUT),
    DefaultRequestHeaders =
    {
        ConnectionClose = true
    }
});

Changing the settings in the HttpClient (or having no custom settings at all) doesn’t fix the issue.
I’ve read that UnityWebRequest might not have these issues, but it can only be called from the main thread and i don’t want to restructure everything to use Coroutines.
EDIT:
Here's the code i use for sending requests and reading the content stream.
internal static async Task<CustomHttpStatusCode> DownloadAsync(URL _URL, Func<string, Task> _ProcessLine, Func<bool> _StopCondition, CancellationToken _CancellationToken)
{
    using var _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    using var _linkedCancellationTokenSource = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(_CancellationToken, _cancellationTokenSource.Token);

    var (_statusCode, _contentStream) = await DownloadAsStreamAsync(_URL, _linkedCancellationTokenSource.Token);

    if (_contentStream == null)
    {
        return _statusCode;
    }

    using (var _streamReader = new StreamReader(_contentStream))
    {
        while (await _streamReader.ReadLineAsync() is {} _currentLine)
        {
            await _ProcessLine(_currentLine);
    
            if (_StopCondition())
            {
                _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
                return CustomHttpStatusCode.Stopped;
            }
        }
    }

    return _statusCode;
}
private static async Task<(CustomHttpStatusCode StatusCode, Stream? ContentStream)> DownloadAsStreamAsync(URL _URL, CancellationToken _CancellationToken)
{
    var _semaphoreAcquired = false;
    var _attempt = 1;
    var _httpStatusCode = CustomHttpStatusCode.Null;
    Stream? _contentStream = null;
    
    do
    {
        try
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000, _CancellationToken);
            await semaphoreSlim.Value.WaitAsync(_CancellationToken);
            _semaphoreAcquired = true;
        
            // I can't add a "using" here since the stream would already be disposed when i try to access it in "DownloadAsync".
            var _response = await httpClient.Value.GetAsync(_URL.AbsoluteUri, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, _CancellationToken);
            
            _httpStatusCode = _response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode().StatusCode.ToCustomHttpStatusCode(); 
            _contentStream = await _response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        
            return (_httpStatusCode, _contentStream);
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException) when (_CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) { /* Expected behavior. */ }
        catch (Exception _exception)
        {
            Debug.LogException(_exception.CustomMessage($"Download attempt [{_attempt}] aborted: {_URL.Bold()} [{_httpStatusCode}]"));
            await Task.Delay(5000 * _attempt++, _CancellationToken);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (_semaphoreAcquired)
            {
                semaphoreSlim.Value.Release();
            }
        }
        
    } while (!_CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested && _attempt <= 3);
    
    return (_httpStatusCode, _contentStream);
}


Can you get a Wireshark trace on the Server and Client Hello packets, maybe there is something going on ther.

Here are the messages from the info column of the last request:
[Certificate, Server Key Exchange, Server Hello Done]
[Client Key Exchange, Change Cipher Spec, Encrypted Handshake Message]
[Client Hello (SNI=httpbin.org)]
[New Session Ticket, Change Cipher Spec, Encrypted Handshake Message]
[Application Data]
[Server Hello]
[Certificate, Server Key Exchange, Server Hello Done]
[Application Data]
[Application Data, Encrypted Alert]
-This is the first time I'm using wireshark so i don't really know what to look for.

That's not terribly useful, except that it seems the handshake is successful, are you sure this trace is from a failing connection? And can you share the trace PCAP file via PasteBin or similar?

Here's a DropBox link https://shorturl.at/aZgGy
And yes, this was the last entry before i stopped after the error occurred in Unity.

I'm not 100% sure that the we request can only be started on the main thread .. you don't have to use a Coroutine to wait for the request either .. you can as well use a thread/task and wait in a while(!webRequest.isDone) .. in general it sounds more like a server sided limitation to me

I don't think it's a server limit, since i tested with two different websites and on both the error occurs at around 1600.
And after i restart Unity it all works again (up until i send 1600 requests).

The TLS exchanges were not the last in the PCAP like you said. I'm seeing many many TCP exchanges of the following, where s is server and c is client: c-ACK, s-SYNACK, c-ACK, c-FINACK, s-ACK. So the client is shutting down the connection without sending anything. There does seem to be an issue with connection reuse though. Can we see the actual code where you use the HttpClient because I suspect a missing using somewhere.

I updated my post with the code you asked for and there's one line where i could add a using, but i don't think that would make any difference, because the test i did with Wireshark had the using statement and i still got the error.

It's just swallowing exceptions and retrying, so not surprising you can't see what's going on, you need better logging of errors. That's compounded by the fact you are not disposing the response or content stream in the event of an exception. If you really do need to return the stream back out a function like that then you need to add _contentStream?.Dispose() in the catch. To be honest I'd probably return the HttpResponseMessage itself rather than the status/content tuple, again with a dispose in the catch.

Thanks for the suggestion to dispose on error, added that to the code.
But what can i improve with the logging? The only thing i swallow is the TaskCanceledException when i canceld it through the token, the rest is cought in the default Exception.

And in that default catch, are you getting any log messages from it?

Yes, there is a Debug.LogException()

It is a bug in Unity, here's the bug report:
issuetracker.unity3d.com
